# Use of DateTime in PHP echo

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have set variables to display current year like this:

```
$now = new DateTime();
$year $now->format("Y");
```

I am using echo like this:

```
echo $str='Hello World, year is $year';
```

This is not displaying the year however, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Single quotes vs double quotes...

Comment: $year = $now->format("Y"); ... You've missed the `=` sign

Comment: Is the missing equal sign a typo in the code or just here?

Comment: unless this is a misstype, this should fix it: $year = $now->format("Y"); Oh, and the quote thing

Comment: You can join strings and variables together with the dot operator as well. For instance: 'Hello World, year is ' . $year;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You're missing an `=` sign in your variable assignment
2. You have your string in single quotes which keeps your variable from being interpolated

.

```
$now = new DateTime();
$year = $now->format("Y");
echo "Hello World, year is $year";
```

Answer (score 3):

replace

```
echo $str='Hello World, year is $year';
```

by

```
echo $str="Hello World, year is $year";
```

Answer (score 2):

First you forgot `=` operator for the `$year`, then you placed `$year` inside single quotes and tried to echo it, which **will not work**, because variables can only function if echoed inside double quotes, not single.

```
$now = new DateTime();
$year = $now->format("Y");
$str = 'somthing';

echo $str."Hello World, year is $year";
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the variable to be echoed then you need to use double quotes instead of single quotes

```
echo "Hello World, year is $year";
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP only parses Strings in double quotes for variables. Either enclose your String in " or use the string concatinator .

> echo 'Hello World, year is' . $year;

or

> echo "Hello World, year is $year";

Besides that you try to echo a variable assigment...